# Can't ping Arch Linux machine from Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, dns, ping, hostname

I have a server and a desktop.

#### Server:

- OS: Ubuntu Server 14.04.1
- IP address: DHCP from Asus router, allocated by MAC address to 192.168.1.4
- Connection: wired Ethernet, always on

#### Desktop:

- OS: Arch Linux
- IP address: DHCP from Asus router, allocated dynamically
- Connection: WiFi (802.11n)

I can ping the server from the desktop (by hostname), but not the desktop from the server (can ping in both directions by IP address, of course). Both machines have winbind installed, both have wins added to /etc/nsswitch.conf, both have avahi-daemon installed and running. Both use the Asus router as their DNS server. What else could be missing?

Comment: Is dns-nameservers defined in /etc/network/interface file?

Comment: It isn't, but I'm on DHCP and manually set my name server via resolv.conf to the IP of the router. (I removed the symlink to avoid overwrites by resolvconf)

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that I had not set a hostname in the DHCP configuration on the Arch machine.

Editing /etc/dhcpcd.conf and adding "hostname myhostname" did the trick.

Really this was an Arch problem, not an Ubuntu one.